# Taking signal travel time into account in Special Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, spacetime

I am having problems taking the time it takes for a light signal from an event to reach an observer into account: For instance, if we have two observers $A$ and $B$ who synchronize their clocks when they pass each other at the origin $O$ and $A$ then emits a light pulse at a time $t$ as measured on their clock, we have the event:

$$X_{1}^\mu=\left(\frac{t}{c},0,0,0\right) \implies X_{1}'^\mu=\left(\frac{\gamma t}{c},-\frac{\beta \gamma t}{c},0,0\right)$$

However, if I'm correct, then $X_{1}'^{\mu}$ is not the time that $B$ observes the signal, it is merely the time which the event takes place in the reference frame at which $B$ is at rest. Therefore we have the actual time that $X_{1}$ is observed in $B$ as:

$$t_{1}'=\gamma t + \frac{\beta \gamma t}{c^{2}}=t\left(\gamma+\frac{\beta\gamma}{c^{2}}\right)$$

Therefore, if $B$ emits a light signal in response $2t$ after they receive the light signal, we have:

$$X_{2}'^{\mu}=\left(\frac{t}{c}\left(2+\gamma + \frac{\beta \gamma}{c^{2}}\right),0,0,0\right) \\\implies X_{2}^\mu = \left(\frac{\gamma\left(2+\gamma+\frac{\beta \gamma}{c^{2}}\right)t}{c},\frac{\beta\gamma\left(2+\gamma+\frac{\beta \gamma}{c^{2}}\right)t}{c},0,0\right)$$

And therefore, the time that $A$ receives the signal would be:

$$t_{2}=\gamma\left(2+\gamma+\frac{\beta\gamma}{c^{2}}\right)t+\frac{\beta\gamma\left(2+\gamma+\frac{\beta\gamma}{c^{2}}\right)}{c^{2}}$$

However, this expression doesn't look right to me as it doesn't simplify and has factors of $c^{2}$, but I'm not sure where I've erred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is not the time that B observes the signal, it is **merely** the time
>   which the event takes place in the reference frame at which B is at
>   rest.

But that's what [observe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_%28special_relativity%29) *means* in SR.  From the Wikipedia article "Observer (special relativity)":

> Physicists use the term "observer" as shorthand for a specific
>   reference frame from which a set of objects or events is being
>   measured. **Speaking of an observer in special relativity is not
>   specifically hypothesizing an individual person who is experiencing
>   events, but rather it is a particular mathematical context which
>   objects and events are to be evaluated from.** The effects of special
>   relativity occur whether or not there is a sentient being within the
>   inertial reference frame to witness them.

---

> Therefore we have the **actual** time that X1 is observed in B as:

No, the time coordinate of event 1 in the primed frame *is* the 'actual' time the *event* is *observed* by B:

$$t'_1 = \gamma t$$

The event that a photon from event 1 arrives at the origin of B's frame is an entirely different event (let's call it event 2) and the time coordinate of that event is *not* the 'actual' time event 1 is observed by B:

$$t'_2 = t'_1 + \beta \gamma t$$

The point is that *seeing* (or photographing) and *observing*, in special relativity, are not synonymous.  For further reading, see "[Photography in Special Relativity](http://users.monash.edu.au/~leo/research/movies/sr/sr-wmv.html)"

> In Special Relativity there is a very specific meaning to the word
>   observer.  An observer is one of an infinite collection, in space and
>   time, of robots whose sole task in life is to record the time and
>   location of each detected event. **When we say that an observation was
>   made we simply mean that the space and time coordinates of an event
>   have been recorded.**
>
> A photograph is a record of all of the photons that were received at
>   the focal point of the camera at the time the photograph was taken.
>
> **These are fundamentally different processes and they give us very
>   different information about the universe.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I'm a little confused as to why you have: $$t'_{2} = t_{1}'+\beta\gamma t$$ Rather than $$t'_{2}=t_{1}'+\frac{\beta\gamma t}{c^{2}}$$ I thought that the distance the photon had to travel (at speed $c$) was $\frac{\beta \gamma t}{c}$?

Comment: @Shaktal, if $v$ is the relative speed of the primed frame in the unprimed frame, the spatial coordinate in the primed frame for event 1 is $x'_1 = -\gamma vt$.  The time required for a photon to propagate from $x'_1$ to the primed origin is then $\Delta t' = \frac{\gamma vt}{c} = \beta \gamma t$